# Filtering out noise from being detected as "moving" foreground in OpenCV/Emgu.CV

Tags: opencv, emgucv

Emgu.CV, a .Net wrapper to OpenCV comes with a video surveillance example. If used with a laptop embedded camera under artificial lightning, the whole picture is "noisy", and a foreground detected by an OpenCV's FGDetector is massive.

What can I do (plain OpenCV answer will also work) to filer out this noise to feed a relatively nosiseless image to a BlobTracker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a simple Background Substraction, where you just have a previous background model and substract it from the current input image to generate a binary image representing 255 - Foreground / 0 - Background, you can look for [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) within the binary image and if they don't occupy a certain minimum area, they are filtered out (turned from 255 to 0).

Using OpenCV, you can use [findContours](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#void%20findContours%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20contours,%20OutputArray%20hierarchy,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20Point%20offset%29) to find all the blobs within the image and use [contourArea](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=contourarea#double%20contourArea%28InputArray%20contour,%20bool%20oriented%29) to check if the blob is big enough to be considered a foreground.

Than you use [fillPolly](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=fillpoly#void%20fillPoly%28Mat&%20img,%20const%20Point%2a%2a%20pts,%20const%20int%2a%20npts,%20int%20ncontours,%20const%20Scalar&%20color,%20int%20lineType,%20int%20shift,%20Point%20offset%29) to fill the big blobs with 255(white) and the small blobs with 0(black).